# Discord.py depositing all money even though sending a integer

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a economy bot with the following code

```
@client.command(aliases=['dp','dep'])
async def deposit(ctx,amount = None):
    #test
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter the amount")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
    if amount=="all" or "max":

      amount = int(bal[0])
        
    amount = int(amount)

    if amount > bal[0]:
        await ctx.send('You do not have sufficient balance')
        return
    if amount < 0:
        await ctx.send('Amount must be positive!')
        return



    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount)
    await update_bank(ctx.author,amount,'bank')
    em=discord.Embed(title="deposited",description=f'{ctx.author.mention} You deposited {amount} coins')
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

async def update_bank(user,change=0,mode = 'wallet'):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open('mainbank.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    bal = users[str(user.id)]['wallet'],users[str(user.id)]['bank']
    return bal
```

Now when I say a!dep 232131231 or a number it deposits all the money , I DONT KNow why it happens please help. I tried many times but it doesnt works
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M297l.png)

Comment: Well, have you tried to remove your `if amount=="all" or "max":` statement and see what effect it has?

Comment: Yes it works but I have got many suggestions/complaints to add a  dep all/max because people dont like copying balance and pasting so I tried to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
if amount=="all" or "max":
```

Always returns `True` therefore `amount = int(bal[0])` code executes.
I think that it is not what you expect.

Replace `if amount=="all" or "max":` with `if amount in ("all", "max"):`.

Also use `is None` instead of `== None`.

Comment: You could use `if amount in {"all", "max"}:` for a small performance gain (list vs set)

Comment: @Ratery Thanks , it worked , thank you , now I will use it in all other commands thank you .

Comment: @TheUltimateGuide , thanks to you too , I will remember that.

Comment: @Ratery I recently got another bug now If I deposit/withdraw money with using all /max it actually doesnt sets bank to 0 but -<amount> please help